# Total sum of multiple columns in Oracle SQL Statement by unique ID

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, unique, multiple-columns

I have a table of members_id and Flags . I want to sum up how many flags a member_id has (like below). I have about 19 Flags which can have a 1 or 0 in the flag field . So basically I want to sum up the 1 in each column per Member_Id

```
Member_Id | Flag2| Flag3| Flag4|Flag5|Flag6|Flag7|Flag8|
999999b     1        0      0    0     1       1      1    
777777a     0        1      1    0     1       0      0
```

Desired Result

```
Member_Id |  Total
999999b        4
777777a        3
```

Comment: You could normalize your table.

Comment: Is your member_id is unique?

Answer (score 9):

You could use:

```
SELECT Member_id, Flag1+Flag2+...+ Flag19 AS total
FROM tab;
```

If any column is nullable you have to handle it for example by using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT Member_id, COALESCE(Flag1,0) + COALESCE(Flag2,0) + ...
FROM tab;
```

Comment: I did do the above but I got back a  list of the member_ids and the totals were empty for every member_id except 1

Comment: @cardonas COALESCE or NVL. You probably have a lot of nulls

Comment: Thank you that was the issue .. I did do the nvl and got the results I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Member_id, sum(Flag1_Flag2_flag3+....Flag19) as Total_Flags from table group by Member_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT member_id, SUM(COALESCE(flag_value, 0)) AS total_value FROM (
    SELECT member_id, flag_name, flag_value
      FROM (
        SELECT member_id, flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5, flag6, flag7, flag8 -- etc.
          FROM yourtable
    ) UNPIVOT (
        flag_value FOR flag_name IN
          ( flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5, flag6, flag7, flag8 )
    )
) GROUP BY member_id;
```

The subquery above is also how you could normalize your data, either in a view, materialized view, or new table:

```
CREATE VIEW yourview AS
SELECT member_id, flag_name, flag_value
  FROM (
    SELECT member_id, flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5, flag6, flag7, flag8 -- etc.
      FROM yourtable
) UNPIVOT (
    flag_value FOR flag_name IN
      ( flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5, flag6, flag7, flag8 )
);
```

Then querying it and summing the values of the flags becomes much easier.

Hope this helps.